# A bug in Matlab comparison?

Tags: matlab, comparison

I write my own version `ismember`(`find_element`) in Matlab to check whether a row array `a` in matrix `b` or not, by comparing `a` with each row in `b`. If each element in `a` 'equals' each element of a row in `b`(if the absolute error is less than `Tol`), then return logic value 1 and row number.

However, when I test my code, I find that Matlab will return `t=[1 1]` when compare `a=1.0e-11*[0.9063 0.0838]` with `B=[-1 0]`(`B` is the second row of `b`). Actually it gives correct absolute error `error=[1.0000 0.0000]`, and clearly `error(1)` is greater than `Tol=1e-6`. Did I find a bug in Matlab? Or is there any error in my code?

The following is my `find_element` code:

```
function [Lia,Locb] = find_element(a,b)
%decide whether a is in b or not(compare each row); if in, return row number
%INPUT:
%a: salar or row array
%b: column array or matrix 
%OUTPUT:
%Lia: 1 if a is in b, 0 if not
%Locb: location of a in b, row number if b is a matrix
Tol = 1e-6; %set tolerance when compare elements
Lia = 0;%initialization
Locb = 0;

t = zeros(size(a));%compare result of each element,logical array
for i = 1:size(b,1) %loop through each row
    for j = 1:size(b,2) %compare each element in each row
        if abs(a(j)-b(i,j))<Tol
            t(j) = 1;
        end
    end
    if t %all 1's
        Lia = 1;%find a in b
        Locb = i;%return row number
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %test outputs
        a
        B=b(i,:)
        error = abs(a-b(i,:))
        t
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        break
    end
end
```

The test code is :

```
a = [9.06319429228031e-12   8.37879678833309e-13];
b = [0 1;-1 0;1 0;0 1];
[Lia Locb] = find_element(a,b)
```

the output is:

```
a =
   1.0e-11 *
    0.9063    0.0838
B =
    -1     0
error =
    1.0000    0.0000
t =
     1     1
Lia =
     1
Locb =
     2
```

Comment: It's really difficult to understand your question but `ismember` only works the way you expect if you specify the `'rows'` input so maybe that's the source of your confusion? Also can you try to rewrite the rest of your question to be a little clearer and actually post your tests as valid MATLAB code in your question? That way we can test it ourselves without having to go request access from your google drive

Comment: is this matlab code? How are you using `#` as a comment character?

Comment: Are you testing against a matrix with more then one row? Or is B = [-1 0] ?

Comment: @Alex Apparently it's Octave. I even use Octave and I didn't realize that you could use # for comments. Weird.

Comment: @Suever I try to write my own function which works like `ismember`. I have updated the question. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Alex This is matlab code. I change all the `%` to `#` because it looks better(grey). This is my first time posting a question on stacks overflow and I did not realize that this will cause difficulty to other people. I have changed it now.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Yes, I am testing against a matrix with more than one row. B is only one row of input matrix b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem in my code now: `t` need to be initialized before checking each row. By putting `t = zeros(size(a))` inside the `i` loop, it works now.

```
...
for i = 1:size(b,1) %loop through each row
    t = zeros(size(a));%compare result of each element,logical array
    for j = 1:size(b,2) %compare each element in each row
....
```

Test and output:

```
>> a = [9.06319429228031e-12    8.37879678833309e-13];
>> b = [0 1;-1 0;1 0;0 1];
>> [Lia Locb] = find_element(a,b)

Lia =

     0


Locb =

     0
```

Comment: yes, I was writing the same answer. Have you concidered replacing the second loop, by directly assigning the result of the condition to t?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger I tried that before and it works.  `for i = 1:size(b,1) %
    t = abs(a-b(i,:))<Tol*ones(size(a));%
   if  t%
        Lia = 1;%
        Locb = i;%
        break%
    end%
end%`

Comment: Matlab is a big fan of vectorized code, as it's compiler will optimize such code with greater efficiency then when using loops.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger I need to rewrite my code in another language like C++ or fortran, that is why I want to rewrite the built-in functions in matlab and try to avoid matlab features. But thank you for your suggestion and I will try to use vectors first when writing in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

After converting `#` to `%`, I find that your code works in Matlab for the following examples. Please provide a clear reproducible answer or edit your question if your problem occurs in Octave.

```
>> a=1.0e-11*[0.9063 0.0838];
>> b=[-1 0];
>> [Lia, Locb] = find_element(a,b)

Lia =

     0


Locb =

     0

>> [Lia, Locb] = find_element([-1.000001 0],b)

a =

           -1            0


B =

    -1     0


error =

        1e-06            0


t =

     1     1


Lia =

     1


Locb =

     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works when `b` is just one row. When `b` is more than one row, `t` stores results of previous rows, so it will not give the correct answer. I feel sorry for the trouble because of my unclear statement. I hope it looks better now.